# News app how to couple categories with userroles

Tags: permissions, categories, roles, 2sxc

I am setting up news with the 2sxc news app. We have multiple categories and some of the categories are only visible for certain userroles, how can I fix this?

What we have tried is diffent modules showing different cateogries but this was not the wish of the client, they want 1 list of news with multiple categories in there.

For example:
A non-user can see the News category articles.
But a subscriber can see the News, Downloads and Publications articles.

But how do I achieve this in 1 list view?

The expected result is that we can name per category what the userrole or roles are which are allowed to see the content. And that it will be filtered out in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the output view to show certain categories but not others. For this, the output view must filter the categories it provides. You can either hardwire this in the view with if-then statements, or add fields to your categories like ShowToAll and then filter by this.